# Julia: Converting PyObject to an Array

Tags: julia, pyobject

In Julia, I am calling a Python module pandas_datareader to download data from the web:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport datetime
@pyimport pandas_datareader.data as web
gdp = web.DataReader("GDPCA","fred",start=datetime.datetime(1929,1,1))
```

The variable gdp is a PyObject object. As such, I cannot manipulate it (take logs for example). How do I convert it to an array? I tried convert(Array{Float64,2},gdp), but it only crashes Julia.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow, please try to format your code to make your question more readable:
(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Looks like your `gdp` is a pandas `DataFrame`. In general, you can [access PyObject attributes by using the `object[:attribute]` syntax](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Formatted the code. What attribute should I be looking for to obtain the downloaded values (and convert them to an array)?

Comment: Possibly [`as_matrix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html)? I'm not sure about the DataFrame-to-array bit with pandas, thus the comment and not answer.

Comment: gdp[:as_matrix] does not work, but gdp[:values] solves it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `@pyimport` macro is used to manipulate the Python objects in this case, pandas DataFrame, via the `PyObject` type. Given `o::PyObject`, `o[:attribute]` is equivalent to `o.attribute` in Python, with automatic type conversion. So the below snippet shows how to obtain a Julia array from a call to Python function,

```
julia> using PyCall
julia> @pyimport datetime
julia> gdp = web.DataReader("GDPCA","fred",start=datetime.datetime(1929,1,1))
julia> typeof(gdp)
PyCall.PyObject
julia> gdp[:values]
87x1 Array{Float64,2}:
1056.6
966.7
904.8
788.2
778.3
...
```